# AS3 Fullscreen hide extra space

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, overflow, fullscreen

I have a 800px600px flash app that has a fullscreen button. When doing fullscreen, the height gets fixed on my monitor, but there is a lot of "overflow", or "extra space" to the sides.

Is there a way to hide this extra space, other than adding a "window" movieclip on the of the movie?

(The blackened space is the movie area, I want to hide everything to the left and right of that area.)

EDIT: What I want is not to change the position/size of the stage/work area, but instead to get something that hides whatever is going on outside of the suposed window(800x600). Something like a "mask" to show only what is going on in that square.

[image: extraspace here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by just drawing a huge yellow (same color as background) square around the stage and leaving a empty area in the middle for the actual app to show.

It may be a bit "silly" solution, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

check out the `fullScreenSourceRect` property of the Stage. That clips the stage to only what you want to show in full screen view. It may look pixelated though, depending on how small that source rect is.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenSourceRect

Comment: I can't seem to achieve what I want using that. I was able to stretch the "area", but not the movie proportions. It still has the same 800*600 proportions, just zoomed out or in.

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand your question, but see if it helps you:

If you are using Event.RESIZE, you can change the size and position of objects in the x and y screen flash, so:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, alterarPosicao);

function alterarPosicao(e:Event):void {
    fundo_escuro.width = stage.stageWidth;
    fundo_escuro.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Thus, whatever the resolution of the project, the objects are aligned to the stage.

Hugs!

Comment: Hey, I liked that custom function name. Thanks. :P